# What mushrooms should I look into for growing in garden aisles?

Tags: mushrooms, hardiness-zone, edible, design, paths

I'm planning out my community garden plot this year, and am considering growing mushrooms where the walking paths will be, and was wondering what types of mushrooms I should look into mixing together to collect throughout the growing season for extra food.

I'm in USDA zone 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two common mushrooms that can grown outside, or in greenhouses, are Pleurotus ostreatus and Agaricus bisporus.  The former is a primary decomposer that would be grown on straw, and the latter is a secondary decomposer that traditionally is grown in composted horse manure.  When grown in greenhouses, Agaricus bisporus is often grown in winter and the heat from the decomposing manure provides some heat to the greenhouse.

Comment: are both edible?

Comment: Of course. All supermarkets should carry them

Comment: I would caution against growing oyster mushrooms in a greenhouse setting due to their prolific spore load and the negative health effects associated with inhaling those spores. If you can ventilate, filter, or pick before they really drop their spores, you could mitigate it. But they can cause visible cloudiness in an enclosed space with surprisingly few mushroom clusters.